# Key Frame Extraction From Video

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, keyframe

I need Need To extract **Key Frames** from Video/Stream.So is there any standard implementation.
I am using open CV.
(Currently i am extracting frames each second which is slower i need to improve performance.)
So if any one has optimized implementation please reply in here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using ffmpeg you can extract all key frames using the following code:

```
ffmpeg -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -i yourvideo.mp4 -vsync 2 -s 160x90 -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

What follows -vf in a ffmpeg command line is a Filtergraph description. The select filter selects frames to pass in output. The constant of the filter is “pict_type” and the value “ PICT_TYPE_I”. So ffmpeg is only passing key frames to the output.

-vsync 2 prevents ffmpeg to generate more than one copy for each key frame.

-f image2 writes video frames to image files. The output filenames are specified by a pattern, which can be used to produce sequentially numbered series of files. The pattern may contain the string "%d" or "%0Nd".

Reference:
http://www.videoproductionslondon.com/blog/scene-change-detection-during-encoding-key-frame-extraction-code

Comment: I get `Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'PICT_TYPE_I)'`

Comment: Hello ! That's a valuable command, however it's order is misplaced and you may be re-sizing the images too. You should put the -i video.mp4 first, before everything else. It goes like : ffmpeg -i "yourInputVideo.mp4" -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -vsync 2 -f image2 thumbnail_%02d.jpeg

Comment: According to [doc here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect), `pict_type` now takes `I` instead of `PICT_TYPE_I`.

Answer (score 8):

I will assume that a *keyframe* is a frame presenting content a lot different from the previous ones (it's not a formal definition, but it fits). Take frames *i* and *i+1*. Use [cv2.absDiff](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=absdiff#cv2.absdiff) to compute the difference between the frames and [cv2.sumElems](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=sum#cv2.sumElems) to get the sum of all pixels differences. Do this for all frames *i*. This will reduce your video stream to an *one dimensional signal*. Look for *peaks* in this signal and pick keyframes corresponding to these peaks.  To find peaks choose a threshold on this signal either manually by finding a frame you deem to be key, and letting its error be the error threshold or automatically using statistics (e.g. any frame i+1 where the error is greater than 1 stdev from the mean error).

Comment: I get an Scalar returned from sumElems() for RGB values. How to handle this scalar the smartest way? Sum RGB channels? Only focus on a certain channel?

Comment: Sum the RGB channels or just use grayscale.

Comment: Can you share a sample code to find the frame at peaks

Comment: coming back to this answer 6 years later, still great!

Answer (score 4):

If something wrong with the above code, try this argument order instead.

```
ffmpeg -i yourVideo.mp4 -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)' -vsync 2 -s 160x90 -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

The ffmpeg solution should work well.

For someone facing problems with the select filter 'eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)', you might want to try the filter as 'eq(pict_type\,I)'. This was broken for a while so some versions of ffmpeg might not recognize the constant. The fix can be seen [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/91cae60ecbf367229013f7d4cc48075634ac8832).

The final command which worked for me finally was:

```
ffmpeg -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)' -i yourVideo.mp4 -vsync 2 -s 160x90 -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ffprobe to extract key frames. It is a tool in ffmpeg.

Use the command:

```
ffprobe in.mp4 -select_streams v -show_entries frame=key_frame,pkt_pts_time -of csv=nk=1:p=0 | findstr "1,"
```