# How to extract key frames from video?

Tags: c#, linux, video, mono

I need to extract all [keyframes (I-frames)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types) from mp4-video as array of [Bitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx).

I've tryed different ffmpeg wrappers: [FFMpeg.NET](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/), [FFMpeg-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/), [FFLib.NET](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/). But all of this projects work only under Windows (maybe I'm wrong, but I can't compile it under my linux machine).

So, how can I solve this problem under linux with Mono?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064962/key-frame-extraction-from-video

Comment: Or here: http://www.videoproductionslondon.com/blog/scene-change-detection-during-encoding-key-frame-extraction-code

Comment: @Patrik yes, my current approach is to extract keyframes as set of jpeg files and load them as array of Bitmaps. But now I want to accelerate it by directly extracting Bitmaps from videofile.

Comment: So, without storing to disk?

Comment: In C you could use libavfilter, so you can use the ffmpeg functionality in code. I'm not sure it's possible to bind them to c#... Anyway, here's a C example, maybe you can use it. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c